# Is there any plugin add browser prefix css3 automatcally in aptana?

Tags: css, aptana

Is there any plugin can do like this:
I'm typing css code:

```
border-radius:5px;
```

and then i press tab or do something and i got it like this:

```
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try pleeease playgrond ( http://pleeease.io/play/ ). Simply you paste your code there, choose options (auto prefix,rem to px,minifizer,etc.) then simply copy respond code and paste ro your css. Or you can try Compass.